# How do I modify a Django filter to search for a specific word and variations with a dash using regex or any other option?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have this filter

```
filters = Q(my_text__icontains=typed_word)
```

I need to modify it in a way that would works like this:
if the typed_word is "ABCD", it should return any ABCD that could have a "-" (dash) at any position in the word, examples:
would return the "ABCD" itself, but also "A-BCD" and "AB-CD" and "ABC-D"

btw any word in the database only have one dash, none of then would have more then one

I tried some patterns using something like this `my_text__iregex=pattern`
But no luck

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a complex regular expression just use the `replace()` function to remove the dash. Something like:

```
select word, replace(word, '-', '') "word without dash"
  from words;
```

See [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/lQf-CpTo).
Note: If your statement *the database only have one dash* must be inforced then you may want to validate the words differ in length by only 1 character. The above will replace all dashes.